# Complex SQL design book

Tags: sql, database, design-patterns

I know SQL but wanted to master it for use in complex SQL and try to create complex SQL statement in one query. Any book to recommend. I found this book: [SQL Design Patterns by Vadim Tropashko](http://www.rampant-books.com/book_0601_sql_coding_styles.htm). What do you folks suggest?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[SQL for Smarties](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Joe-Celkos-SQL-Smarties-Programming/dp/1558605762) by Joe Celko. I like the way it covers methods for representing datasets that you'd not immediately think would fit into a relational model.

[image]
<sub>(source: [amazon.com](http://images.amazon.com/images/P/0123693799.01._SX140_SY225_SCLZZZZZZZ_.jpg))</sub>

Comment: +1.  Gonna have to go find this one.

Comment: A newer (2010) edition is out :) http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/12232564-joe-celko-s-sql-for-smarties

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking SQL Server, the series of SQL books by [Solid Quality Mentors](http://www.solidq.com/na/OurBooks.aspx) are well worth a read.

I personally can recommend:

- [Inside Microsoft SQL Server 2005: T-SQL Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735621977)
- [Inside Microsoft SQL Server 2005: T-SQL Querying](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735623139)
- [Inside Microsoft SQL Server 2005: Query Tuning and Optimization](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735621969)

I think they're a great set to have on your bookcase.

Answer (score 2):

for T-SQL, take a look at look at books by Itzik Ben-Gan:

http://www.solidq.com/insidetsql/

Answer (score 2):

+1 for Joe Celko

also,  for sql server  [The Gurus guide to transact sql](http://books.google.com/books?id=w-MeFuIv8rgC&dq)